# perl - range between with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file like

```
$ cat num_range.txt
rate1, rate2, rate3, rate4, rate5
pay1, pay2, rate1, rate2, rate3, rate4
rev1, rev2
rate2, rate3, rate4
```

And I need to filter the comma-separated rows by matching against a prefix and a numeric range.
For example - if the input is "rate" and range is 2 to 5, then I should get

```
rate2, rate3, rate4, rate5
rate2, rate3, rate4
rate2, rate3, rate4
```

If it is 5 to 10, then I should get

```
rate5
```

when I use `perl -ne ' while ( /rate(\d)/g ) { print "$&," } ; print "\n" '  num_range.txt` I get all the matches for the prefix,

But below one is not working.

```
perl -ne ' while ( /rate(\d){2,5}/g ) { print "$&," } ; print "\n" '  num_range.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does nothing to compare the matched number to the range.

Also, you are gratuitously printing a comma after the last entry.

Try this instead.

```
perl -ne '$sep = ""; while (/(rate(\d+))/g ) {
    if ($2 >= 2 and $2 <= 5) {
        print "$sep$1"; $sep=", ";
    }
}
print "\n" if $sep' num_range.txt
```

Notice also how `\d+` is used to match any number after `rate` and extracted into a separate numeric comparison. This is slightly clumsy in isolation, but easy to adapt to different number ranges.

Comment: great!.. this is robust.. you covered all my corner cases as well..

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way

```
perl -wnE'
    print join",", grep { /rate([0-9]+)/ and $1 >= 2 and $1 <= 5 } split /\s*,\s*/
' file
```

The hard-coded keyword `rate` and limits (`2` and `5`) can of course be variables set from input

Answer (score 1):

To explain why your code isn't working:

> ```
> /rate(\d){2,5}/g
> ```

This doesn't do what you think it does. The `{x,y}` syntax defines the *number of times* the previous string occurs.

So this matches "the string 'rate' followed by between 2 and 5 digits". And that won't match anything in your data.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
perl -anE '@rates=();while(/rate(\d+)/g){push @rates,$& if $1>=2 && $1<=15}say"@rates" if @rates' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
rate2 rate3 rate4 rate5
rate2 rate3 rate4
rate2 rate3 rate4
```

Comment: It doesn't; the regex hardcodes the range 2 to 5. It should not be hard to figure out how to replace it with a regex which matches a different range, though in the general case, regexes are not very convenient for expressing arbitrary number ranges.

Comment: @stack0114106: Well you said you want a range between `2` & `5`

Comment: @stack0114106:See my edit for other ranges.

Comment: @stack0114106: You're welcome. Don't worry about downvote I don't take care of it when there are no comments that explain why.